# How to color columns when exporting to Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following code to export data to an Excel sheet. I need your help to know how I can color the sheet columns in other colors?

```
System.Data.DataTable dit = null;
try
{
    dit = BindGrid();
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dit, "Students");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Download.xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
}
finally
{
    dit = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Excel = using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

public void ExportToExcel(DataGridView gridviewID, string excelFilename)
    {
        string path = excelFilename + ".xlsx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        app.Visible = true;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
        }
        workbook.SaveCopyAs(path);
        workbook.Saved = true;
        workbook.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }
```